# Fort rabbit and Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql, fortrabbit

I'd like to use fortrabbit with Google Cloud SQL. Google's Cloud SQL requires to whitelist any IPs that want to access the db, and it seems that fort rabbit doesn't guarantee the outbound IP?  How can I access my Cloud SQL data from fortrabbit?

Answer (score 0):

[edit] Cloud SQL does not support whitelisting all IP's like 0.0.0.0. Having said that, it's enough if you can provide a subnet that can catch all the IP's from which your connections can possibly originate from. If you provide a broad IP range for the authorized subnet, please make sure your database is protected with strong user-name and passwords to protect from unauthorized access.